# How to dynamically add a new column to an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table to which I am currently dynamically adding rows: http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/5/

Now I'd like to add a new column to the table as well with a click of a button. The user will enter the column header in a textbox.

How can I achieve this? If the user adds 4 rows, the `Add a new Column` button should take care of all the existing rows (adding checkbox in each one).

**update**

I'm looking to add column name and checkbox at row level.

so I've added the text box in which the user will input the column name: http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/10/

```
<input type=text placeholder='columnname'/>
<button type="button" id="btnAddCol">Add new column</button></br></br>
```

so then when user clicks the button the columnname should be the value in the textbox and at the row level should be checkboxes. So basically the new column should be appended to all `tr` in the table except the first row since that is the column names

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/6/ Should do what you want.

Comment: sberry this will add `Foo` to both column header and row. I changed it to `$(el).append("<td><input type=checkbox/></td>"); ` but that then adds chcekbox to both column name and row...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with a small example how you could do that.

[jsFiddle - Link](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/11/)

```
var myform = $('#myform'),
    iter = 0;

$('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
     myform.find('tr').each(function(){
         var trow = $(this);
         if(trow.index() === 0){
             trow.append('<td>Col+'iter+'</td>');
         }else{
             trow.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="cb'+iter+'"/></td>');
         }
     });
     iter += 1;
});
```

This would add a new column to every row, including an count-variable that gets applied to the first row as name and to the name-attribute of the checkboxes on the following rows.

Consider using `th` - elements for the table header, that way you wouldn't need the index-check i'm making and it would be more semantically correct.

I left out the part where the user would put in a name for the column, but as you see, you could just replace the `iter` - value with that in the end.

Comment: Inspired by this answer, modern alternative with pure javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57593040/1248177

Answer (score 17):

Modern pure JavaScript solution:

```js
const addColumn = () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#table tr')].forEach((row, i) => {
        const input = document.createElement("input")
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
        const cell = document.createElement(i ? "td" : "th")
        cell.appendChild(input)
        row.appendChild(cell)
    });
 }
 
 document.querySelector('button').onclick = addColumn
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><th><input type="text" value="test 1" /><th/></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" value="test 2" /><td/></tr>
</table>

<button type="button">add column</button>
```

First row will contain a `th` instead of `td`. Each new cell contains a `input`. Feel free to change this to suit your need.

Comment: Can you point me to documentation or an explanation of the syntax for:  createElement(i ? "td" : "th").  I can't figure out how to alter this to allow, for instance, th to be a different input than td.

Comment: Do you mean the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?

Comment: And `td` is not an `input`. It is a cell containing the `input`.

Comment: Ternary operator, yes, thank you.  And sorry... to clarify, I meant more like an input on the td tag but different on the th tag.

Comment: @SaintFrag You have to transform `cell.appendChild(input)` into `cell.appendChild(i ? input : fooBar)` where fooBar is any kind of html element like a div  `const fooBar = document.createElement("div")`

Comment: Bingo.  Thank you for that information:  I quickly got it working exactly as I was hoping for.  Now I have Ternary operators in my still-developing arsenal.

Comment: Glad you figure it out. Ternary operator is a lovely tool, but dont over-nest them ;)

Answer (score 4):

The answer works, but still here is an alternative way where we use thead and tbody !

```
JS

$('#irow').click(function(){
if($('#row').val()){
    $('#mtable tbody').append($("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone());
    $('#mtable tbody tr:last :checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
}
});
$('#icol').click(function(){
if($('#col').val()){
    $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>"));
    $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
    $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="checkbox">'))});
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code for adding new column:

```
$('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
    $("tr").append("<td>New Column</td>");
});
```

But you need to change the value for the first row with a text and others to include a `<input type="checkbox" />`. And it is better to

Answer (score 2):

Check it out jsFiddle .............................
http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/8/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
              var count = 3, first_row = $('#Row2');
                while(count-- > 0)                    first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
     });   

        $('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
            $("#blacklistgrid tr").each(function(){
               $(this).append("<td>test</td>");       
            })
     });      
 });
```

Comment: Please see the update. I would like to add a checkbox at the row level.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table of 4 columns:

[image]

I can add values dinamically like this:

```
 var TableId = "table_" + id; 

 var table = $("#" + TableId );

 table.find("tbody tr").remove();
                                            
 table.append("<tr><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + "lorem"  + "</td><td>" + "ipsum" + "</td><td>" + "dolor" + "</td></tr>");
```

and the final result will be:

[image]