# Add columns to table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a table that gives an overview of the events a user went to. I've created a table for this. What I want to do know is to check based on the user id, if he's registered for a certain event and display those events.

Here's my Html code:

```
<div id="modal2" class="modal modal-fixed-footer col l4 ">
  <div class="modal-content col l4">
    <table class="centered bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id">Datum</th>
          <th data-field="name">Event</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="datum">11/04/2014</td>
          <td id="eventnaam">Cleantech</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Sluiten</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
var Append = function (waardes) {console.log("halloblo")

 var newEvent = $('#modal2').clone(true);
 newEvent.attr('id',waardes.ID);
 console.log(newEvent);

 var eventnaam = newEvent.find('#eventnaam');
 eventnaam.text(waardes.Naam);
 console.log(eventnaam);

 var eventdatum = newEvent.find('#datum');
 eventdatum.text(waardes.Datum);

}
```

I already checked if I go into my function Append!

Comment: You're going to get duplicate `id`'s within the DOM if you keep `cloning` try selecting using css selectors instead.

Comment: Sorry, i do not get this. Can you give an example?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add a new column to an HTML table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964253/how-to-dynamically-add-a-new-column-to-an-html-table)

Comment: @Liam How can i duplicate my rows in the table. I want to duplicate this with values from my database

Answer (score 0):

You just try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/11/)

I updated your fiddle with a small example how you could do that.

You can add rows and columns

Html

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
  <table id="blacklistgrid">
    <tr id="Row1">
      <td class="space">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2">
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="shade" name="shade" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="red" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="green" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add few more Rows!</button>
</br>
</br>
<button type="button" id="btnAddCol">Add new column</button>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Add Rows
 $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
   var count = 3,
   first_row = $('#Row2');
   while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
 });
 // Add Columns
 var myform = $('#myform'),
 iter = 0;
 $('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
   myform.find('tr').each(function(){
     var trow = $(this);
     if(trow.index() === 0){
       trow.append('<td>Col'+iter+'</td>');
     }else{
       trow.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="cb'+iter+'"/></td>');
     }
   });
   iter += 1;
 });
});
```

Css

```
td {
  padding-right: 15px
}
.space {
  padding-right: 75px;
}
```

Comment: And if I want to do this with rows?

Comment: Yes i want to add multiple rows based on values from my database

Comment: You can check this.

Comment: I tried your code but the problem is that i've multiple events in my database and the aren't placed on a new row.

Comment: No, see my comment below

Comment: I just added my screenshot of the result

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in JS:

```
var Append = function (waardes) {
 var first_row =$('#row2');
 first_row.clone(true).appendTo('#modal2');

 var eventnaam = first_row.find('#eventnaam');
 eventnaam.text(waardes.Naam);

 var eventdatum = first_row.find('#datum');
 eventdatum.text(waardes.Datum);
}
```

And this is my code in HTML:

```
<div id="modal2" class="modal modal-fixed-footer col l4 ">
  <div class="modal-content col l4">
    <table class="centered bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id">Datum</th>
          <th data-field="name">Event</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr id="row2">
          <td id="datum"></td>
          <td id="eventnaam"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Sluiten</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result I get: [Screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqiUv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to add a column to a table with pure javascript:

```
function addColumnToTableJS(table, pos, content){
  if (typeof table === 'string'){
      table = document.getElementById(table);
  }
  var columns = table.rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
  if (!pos && pos !== 0){
    pos = columns;
  }
  var rowregex = new RegExp('{ROWINDEX}', 'g');
  var colregex = new RegExp('{COLINDEX}', 'g');
  for (var r=0; r<table.rows.length; r++){
    var cell = table.rows[r].insertCell(pos);
    cell.innerHTML = content
      .replace(rowregex, String.fromCharCode(65 + r))
      .replace(colregex, columns + 1); 
  }
}
```

In its simplest usage, call like this to add column to the left:

```
addColumnToTableJS('table1', 0, '<td>test</td>')
```

Or like this to add the column to the right:

```
addColumnToTableJS('table1', null, '<td>test</td>')
```

Here's an example:

https://jsbin.com/voxibufomu/1/edit?html,js,output